# ComboBoxItem Selectvalue is Empty in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ddDate" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="170" Margin="0,4,0,0" Style="{StaticResource Light-ComboBoxStyle}">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DropDownSelectionChanged" cal:View.Model="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMResource}}">

                <!--<cal:Parameter Value="{Binding Hierarchy}" />-->


            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Current Week</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Last Week</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Year to Date</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

ComboxItem Value by default not selected when i have added attribute isSelected = True.

Comment: show us the entire declaration of the combobox and How you are binding the Combobox selecteditem !

Comment: Try to bind the SelectedItem in Mode=OneWayToSource instead of default (TwoWay I think)

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention that each item in the combobox is ComboBoxItem therefore if you bind it to a string it will give you the value of ComboBoxItem.ToString()

You can use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath properties to force the binding give you the value of each comboBoxItem content:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="ddDate" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="170" Margin="0,4,0,0">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Current Week</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Last Week</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Year to Date</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```